# Annoying wsgen tool pop up when publish server

Tags: eclipse, websphere

When i start publish my application from WebSphere Application Server then it will always pop up a dialog box "Generation Result for Wsgen" which i need to click "okay" to close it, after that it will keep on pop up and i need to click okay until the server are successfully publish.

Do anyone know how to fix this ? I'm looking solution from online but there is no solution about this.

attached is the image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxrsk.jpg

[image: wsgen]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the IBM Liberty Developer Tools for Eclipse, then use at least version 18.0.0.4.  You can get the latest release from here:

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-IBM_Liberty_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_2019-03_4.11